# convert declarative pipeline to scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I already used the following declarative script as a part of my cleanup script, now I should convert it to the scripted pipeline, how I can convert the post to the scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripted equivalent to the declarative

```
steps {
  // pipeline steps here
post {
  failure {
    // failure handler here
  }
  success {
    // success handler here
  }
  always {
    // always handler here
  }
}
```

is the native Groovy `try { } catch { }`:

```
try {
  // pipeline steps here

  // success handler here
} catch(Exception e) {
  // failure handler here
} finally {
  // always handler here
}
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head how to add an abort handler, but I think you might be able to do it by inspecting the `currentBuild.result` variable in the failure handler block.